# Are there existing tools that raytrace triangle meshes?

Tags: graphics, polygon, mesh, raytracing

*Disclaimer: I'm not 100% on whether this is a well-formed question, so please feel free to comment and suggest improvements. I'll be actively looking out for ways to improve this question.*

I have a triangle mesh, let's say the [Stanford Bunny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_bunny).  Now, I want to raycast a ray from a source point in 3D along a 3D direction vector, and identify just the first intersection of that ray with the triangle mesh.

I already have a naive implementation cooked up.  However, I'm looking for a more advanced implementation.  In particular, I'll be casting many millions of rays in many directions, so I'm looking for a multi-threaded or GPU-accelerated implementation.

I have to believe that there must be some pretty complete projects online, as raycasting triangle meshes is a fundamental part of 3D computer graphics.  However, I can't find anything beyond personal projects, which leads me to believe that I am using the wrong search terms, or something pretty simple along those lines.

**I am looking for suggestions on existing tools that can raytrace polygonal meshes.**

Comment: Any rendering application? And what is wrong with the private projects you found?

Comment: So here's the thing -- I don't need any rendering at all.  I just need to be able to find the distance to the mesh.  That's it.  Nothing super fancy is needed.

Comment: The private projects I've found are naive, single-threaded, memory-inefficient, etc.  Moreover, I'd be very inclined to believe that there should be at least a couple of relatively big-name open-source projects out there, given the importance of scientific visualization.

Comment: [CGAL's AABBTree](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/index.html) provides the necessary queries. And probably any open source raytracer (e.g. [Mitsuba](https://www.mitsuba-renderer.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is find the distance to the mesh for millions of rays. Then it might be a good idea to look up CUDA raytracing tutorial online. This will show you how to cast many millions of rays. In most tutorials, raytracing is used to render to the screen with the camera matrix. However, this is not necessary. Simply adjust the rays starting parameters to what you need them to be such as 3D vector and position. Then output the data back to the CPU. Be weary of the bandwidth between the GPU and CPU sending millions of intersection points between the CPU and GPU can make the program run exceptionally slow.